# Asynchronously call CollectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst?

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, collectionview

Asynchronously call CollectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops found it:

```
cv.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(AddressOf cv.MoveCurrentToFirst))
```